# Detect key press combination in Linux with Python?

Tags: python, linux, keylogger

I'm trying to capture key presses so that when a given combination is pressed I trigger an event.

I've searched around for tips on how to get started and the simplest code snippet I can find is in Python - I grabbed the code below for it from [here](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread112975.html). However, when I run this from a terminal and hit some keys, after the "Press a key..." statement nothing happens.

Am I being stupid? Can anyone explain why nothing happens, or suggest a better way of achieving this on Linux (any language considered!)?

```
import Tkinter as tk

def key(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Escape':
        root.destroy()
    print event.char

root = tk.Tk()
print "Press a key (Escape key to exit):"
root.bind_all('<Key>', key)
# don't show the tk window
root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out there is a much simpler answer when using GNOME which doesn't involve any programming at all...

http://www.captain.at/howto-gnome-custom-hotkey-keyboard-shortcut.php

[Archived on Wayback](https://web.archive.org/web/20070802112319/http://www.captain.at/howto-gnome-custom-hotkey-keyboard-shortcut.php)

Just create the script/executable to be triggered by the key combination and point the 'keybinding_commands' entry you create in gconf-editor at it.

Why didn't I think of that earlier?

Answer (score 3):

Tk does not seem to get it if you do not display the window. Try:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def key(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Escape':
        root.destroy()
    print event.char

root = tk.Tk()
print "Press a key (Escape key to exit):"
root.bind_all('<Key>', key)
# don't show the tk window
# root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

works for me...

Comment: Hmm, this works - thanks - but I don't really want the window being displayed. I'm aiming to have a background process that sits and waits  for the combination.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not know how you would achieve that, but at least you have a new direction for further research.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is reading `/dev/tty` in "raw" mode.

Normal Linux input is "cooked" -- backspaces and line endings have been handled for you.

To read a device like your keyboard in "raw" mode, you need to make direct Linux API calls to IOCTL.

Look at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/68397/ for some guidance on this.  Yes, the recipe is in tcl, but it gives you  a hint as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (a non-Python option) use [XBindKeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html).

Answer (score 0):

tkinter 'bind' method only works when tkinter window is active.

If you want binding keystrokes combinations that works in all desktop (global key/mouse binding) you can use [bindglobal](https://github.com/segalion/bindglobal) (install with `pip install bindglobal`). It works exactly like standard tkinter 'bind'.

Example code:

```
import bindglobal
def callback(e):
    print("CALLBACK event=" + str(e))

bg = bindglobal.BindGlobal()
bg.gbind("<Menu-1>",callback)
bg.start()
```