# How to detect key-press combinations in background on linux & windows with python?

Tags: linux, windows, python-3.x, keypress

how can I detect key-press combinations in background using python for linux and windows ?

for example,

> when `Ctrl+v` is detected execute `doThis()` in background
>
> when `Tab` is detected execute `doThat()` in background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on windows this can be done using 
 [pyhook](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/)

on ubuntu I did it with help of this
 [pyxhook](https://github.com/JeffHoogland/pyxhook)

Edit: another awesome library for Windows & Linux - [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard)

Comment: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard is also available but you must be root on linux

Comment: @Calumah that looks really nice library 
thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3):

If you are using python tkinter, having filemenu. then below code might help you.

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys
import Tkinter

class App(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        menubar = Tkinter.Menu(self)
        fileMenu = Tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="doThat", underline=1,
                             command=quit, accelerator="Ctrl+v")
        fileMenu.add_command(label="doThis", underline=1,
                             command=quit, accelerator="Tab")
        self.config(menu=menubar)

        self.bind_all("<Control-v>", self.doThat)
        self.bind_all("<Tab>", self.doThis)

    def doThat(self, event):
        print("Control v is pressed ...")

    def doThis(self, event):
        print("Tab is pressed...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback. How can I can make it work even when it is minimised ?

Comment: Can you check with below link: if it answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515801/detect-key-press-combination-in-linux-with-python?rq=1

Comment: that will work only for ubuntu, pyhook and pyxhook seems legit

Answer (score 0):

[pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard) worked the best for me.